# Missing special characters in Leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to display the proper name of cities with special characters in spanish such as 'tilde' Á, however I'm getting false encoding in the popup layers as you can see in the image:

[image: leaflet popup wrong encoding UTF-8]
I have my html charset defined as `<meta charset="utf-8" />` and the .geojson is also alright:

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{
"type":"Point","coordinates":[-74.1059716,4.650528403]},
"properties":{
"DPTO_CCDGO":11.000000,
"MPIO_CCDGO":1.000000,
"CPOB_CNMBR":"BOGOTÁ D.C.",
"CPOB_NANO":2011.000000,
(...)
```

Any idea on how to fix it? 
I already checked with Chrome 58 and Firefox 53 with same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem, then I saw that my geojson wasn't encoded in UTF-8. Converting the geojson's encoding to UTF-8 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I changed the File Encoding easily with 'Sublime Text'. It was just `File > Save with Encoding > UTF-8` and that's it.